# How to give exception to specific URL in nginx, where website is redirected to another URL

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, server, return, reverse-proxy

```
server {
    server_name example.test.com;

    location / {
        return 301 http://test.com/example$request_uri;
    }
    location ^~ /.well-known/{
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.test.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.test.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.test.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.test.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

In above configuration, I want to redirect example.test.com to test.com/example but except example.test.com/.well-known/asset.json